# Is there a way to pass the return value of a decorator to function args?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-decorators

I would like to know if this is possible. For example:

```
def decorator(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper_decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        x = 5 * 10
        value = func(*args, **kwargs)
        # Do something after
        return value
    return wrapper_decorator


@decorator
def mult(x):
   y = x/5
   print y #should print 10
```

Is there documentation or somthing like that?

Comment: You can pass different arguments into `func` if that's what you're asking.

Comment: `func(x, *args, **kwargs)`…?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for @deceze. Thanks a lot.